# Assigning method that takes a pointer to Func<>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to conditionally assign a Method to a `Func<>`. The method I'm trying to assign takes a pointer argument, which it seems C# does not seem to allow me to use along with a `Func<>`. Here's the code.

```
Func<ulong, ulong, ulong*, ulong> Multiply64Func;

if (Bmi2.X64.IsSupported)
{
    Multiply64Func = Bmi2.X64.MultiplyNoFlags;
}
else
{
    Multiply64Func = Multiply64;
}
```

And here's how I want to use it later:

```
hi = Multiply64Func(c[0], b[0], loPtr);
```

And the corresponding error: `error CS0306: The type 'ulong*' may not be used as a type argument`

What's a workaround for this, or is there a way to get it to work?

Of course, I could just do this:

```
hi = Bmi2.X64.IsSupported ? Bmi2.X64.MultiplyNoFlags(c[0], b[0], loPtr) : Multiply64(c[0], b[0], loPtr);
```

However, this section of code is *very* performance critical, and I see a notable speed decrease from checking this in a hot loop - hence why I want to perform the comparison once, and assign the corresponding method to a function.

The more C# thing to do would be to take a `ref` param - But I can't change the signature of `Bmi2.X64.MultiplyNoFlags;` since it's not my code.

Comment: Can you explain why youre using generics in the first place?

Comment: Also, the CLR does impose a cost to invoking via a delegate. If you have perf constraints I would avoid any use of a delegate.

Comment: @EricLippert Not sure what you mean by that, is there a preferred way to assign a method to a variable? The method I'm calling is not generic. Is it impossible to assign a method to a variable without a performance loss? I could perform the check and call an alternative function - but that would result in a lot of duplicated code for just a one line change.

Comment: `Func` itself is generic. You could declare a non-generic delegate like `unsafe delegate uint Multiply64Func(uint a, uint b, uint* c);` and use that instead of `Func<uint,uint,uint*,uint>`, but you'll still get the delegate performance hit.

Comment: No I mean why are you trying to use a generic delegate?

Comment: And if the check is expensive then why is that not the thing to cache? I'm confused by this question -- you seem to be making things needlessly difficult. Since you cannot use a generic delegate and do not need to use a generic delegate, dont use a generic delegate!

Comment: It's just a boolean check, but if I perform the check each time in the loop, (It runs approximately 500,000 times), then I'm reading that variable 500,000 times when I could just be calling the correct method straight away, no?

Comment: Your proposal is to trade doing an expensive delegate invocation to avoid a cheap bool check. That sounds like a bad trade. But measure it, and then make an informed decision

Comment: A non generic delegate does indeed work - I guess I was searching for the wrong thing - Thanks. It does indeed seem slightly slower than checking the bool each iteration. Is there no way to avoid both slow downs, other than duplicating the function, with each version using an alternative multiply func? Continuing my profiling.. seems hard to tell if this actually has much of an impact - hard to measure a ~5% change accurately. Maybe I'm optimizing the wrong section.

Comment: After some more profiling, it seems like just dispatching to another method once is the best way. Both checking the boolean in the loop, caching the boolean, and using a delegate, add a roughly 2% overhead.

Comment: Well there is no free lunch. Any time you make a decision that takes you down one of two code paths, you've got to (1) take the hit of making the decision, and (2) live in a world where branch prediction is wrong about half the time. Both are perf hits. Now, if your question is "can I invoke a function pointer in C# without storing that function pointer in a delegate?" the short answer is "no". The long answer is: I tried adding that feature to C# and though it worked, we never came up with a suitable syntax.

Comment: The proposal was to generate a syntax that would cause the compiler to emit a `calli` instruction; this idea occasionally comes back. See the roslyn github forum; maybe someone is discussing it. If you have a good use case for them, that would be points towards the feature.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this section of code is very performance critical, and I see a notable speed decrease from checking this in a hot loop - hence why I want to perform the comparison once

Cache the result in a Boolean and use your simple answer.

```
bool useBmi = Bmi2.X64.IsSupported;

while (expensiveLoop)
{
    hi =  useBmi ? Bmi2.X64.MultiplyNoFlags(c[0], b[0], loPtr) : Multiply64(c[0], b[0], loPtr);
}
```

If you insist on using a delegate you could do this:

```
bool useBmi = Bmi2.X64.IsSupported;
ulong hi;  //Must be declared outside the loop

Action multiply = useBmi
                ? new Action( () => { hi = Bmi2.X64.MultiplyNoFlags(c[0], b[0], loPtr); })
                : new Action( () => { hi = Multiply64(c[0], b[0], loPtr); } );


while (expensiveLoop)
{
    multiply();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would be faster, `Bmi2.X64.IsSupported;` is a bool itself, why would assigning to a local variable be quicker? Do we still not need to check it each time in the loop - or is the branch predictor able to figure out that it's always true/false with more ease this way?

Trying to profile the performance, but it's only about a 5% difference, so hard to say for sure the effects.

Comment: Wasn't clear if it was a static property or a field. I'm surprised it's the single Boolean comparison that is at issue. I've added a technique that uses a delegate.

Comment: This is the definition - `public static bool IsSupported { [Intrinsic] get { return false; } }` - I'm not exactly sure how that works, and if it has an overhead - I assumed if I wasn't invoking a method that it was always a constant performance cost to access.

Comment: The various Intrinsic `IsSupported` flags, as well and `Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated`, have special case handling in the JIT compiler and will not be executed at runtime. A conditional test on these flags guides the JITter and modifies what CPU instructions to emit, but it does not result in the a conditional branch at runtime. As such it is safe to put these tests inside of high performance tight loops.